# why wont the particles show up on this mesh?

Tags: particles

I've set the grass particle to work off 'density' in the vertex groups. first time this has happened. there are no modifiers except 2 particle systems on this object. is this a glitch or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this makes a difference with your file since we don't have a stripped down version uploaded to look at, but one of your particle systems is set to not be visible. Is that on purpose?

Comment: no both of the particle systems were set to the same vertex group. I managed to fix the problem by painting in weight paint the what seemed to update the system then reapply the weights in edit mode. It now works fine so must be a bug